# Testing WebAPI and front end in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm building a WebAPI and a front end which calls services in the web api. It looks like the only way to call WebAPI functions from the front end is to have the WebAPI running in IIS when the front end makes the calls.

This means it's not possible to debug the WebAPI and front end in the same project as Visual Studio can only run and debug one project at a time (unless I'm mistaken?)

I'm using a work around where I include the WebAPI project as a reference in the front end along with the database connection strings and dependency injections it would otherwise have called in its start up.

The setup is working fine now and I can debug webapi and the frontend from the same solution.

are there any downsides to this when it comes time to take apart the webapi and the frontend and deploy them?

Comment: You are mistaken in your assumption about debugging multiple projects in VS: [Debug Multiple Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx). The tool has been able to this for a while. This applies to VS 2017, too.

Comment: @R.Richards ah yep that looks like a legitamite solution, unfortunately my webapi calls start failing when I do that '"TypeError: Failed to fetch"' so not sure if this is a limitation of that method or something else..

Comment: As long as you have each project that starts configured to run on different port numbers, there shouldn't be any conflicts between them.

Comment: @R.Richards I looked into what you described and it was exactly what I wanted. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that Visual Studio has supported for some time. It is a nice feature of the tool, too.

Let's say you have a solution that includes an MVC web application, and a API application that the MVC application calls to. In order to be able to debug to 2 applications at the same time open the solution properties, and choose the *Multiple startup projects* option on the Common Properties/Startup Project pane. Set the MVC and API project *Action* to *Start*. You may want to set the API project to start before the MVC project since there is a dependency there.

As long as you have each project that starts configured to run on different port numbers, there shouldn't be any conflicts between them.

You can confirm that the ports don't conflict by opening the Project Properties for each project, and go to the *Debug* tab. Look in the *App URL* setting under *Web Server Settings*. The default value will be `http://localhost:{port}/`; the port will vary from one project to another. Just make sure the 2 projects aren't using the same port number.

Happy debugging!